# How to know HDFS concurrent throughput in MR2

Tags: performance, hadoop, hdfs, throughput

I'm new to Hadoop. Recently I'm trying to use TestDFSIO to evaluate my
hdfs performance, and I've a question about concurrent throughput:

**In MR 1**

Concurrent Throughput = Reported Throughput x Number of Map Slots

**For example**

```
Throughput MB/sec: 141.4427 
Map Slots=2 
Concurrent Throughput = 282.8854 MB/sec.
```

But in MR2 (both map and reduce slot are no longer exist in YARN), how do I calculate the concurrent throughput?

Comment: Gentlemen, are you sure concurrent throughput is about number of slots? It is actually about number of slots actually used! Which can influence severe difference. And having this approach you will have no issue with MR2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is good simple article which explains most of math behind these 'concurent' words:

[Benchmarking and Stress Testing an Hadoop Cluster With TeraSort, TestDFSIO & Co.](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/)

Concurrent throughput is about how much data you indeed can process (through given number of mappers or reducers). If you have 100 mapper slots but your job needs only 4 mappers - you only have 4 x average throughput. In YARN you have limit amount of containers. So concurrent throughput will be about

[average throughput] x [number of containers practically used].

But why at all do you need this metric which tells you nothing?
For example if your cluster is going to be heterogeneous (they go sooner or later) you never receive full load. The same situation happens if you have lot of 'waves' in your job.

Real power of Hadoop cluster is not about cluster itself but adoption of your job to Hadoop model in general and your cluster balance for specific case. I periodically have situation where my better tuned staging cluster beats production cluster on customer side. And this often leads to negotiation about customer cluster configuration or hardware balance, because they often don't account their own specifics. But their hardware is without any question better then mine one.